# Как реализовать такой блок как на картинке

Tags: flexbox

Есть блок как на картинке, где находяться фотографии путешествия.Как реализовать такой блок при помощи Flex технологии[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 2):

Вариант 1:

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: yellow;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.group{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.el {
  width: calc(100%-10px);
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.el-1 {
  flex: 1;
}
.el-2 {
  flex: 2;
}
.el-3 {
  flex: 3;
}
.el-4 {
  flex: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="group">
    <div class="el el-2"></div>
    <div class="el el-3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="el el-1"></div>
    <div class="el el-4"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="el el-4"></div>
    <div class="el el-1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="el el-3"></div>
    <div class="el el-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вариант 2:

```css
.wrapper {
  column-count: 4;
  column-gap: 3px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.el {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.el:nth-child(2n) {
  height: 50px;
}

.el:nth-child(3n) {
  height: 80px;
}

.el:nth-child(4n) {
  height: 30x;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div>
```

Comment: подкорректировал второй